# If i add async keyword to a method which which should return a Task it wrap the return value in Task?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

if write this function without async and await as this example i get error that i should return Task not User object

```
public Task<User> Register(User user, string password)
    {
        byte[] passwordhash,passwordsalt;

        CreatePassword(password,out passwordhash,out passwordsalt);

        return user;
    }
```

but if write this function with async and await as this example it work correctly, so i want to know if add async keyword to any method it should wrap the returned value to a Task automaticily

```
public async Task<User> Register(User user, string password)
    {
        byte[] passwordhash,passwordsalt;
        CreatePassword(password,out passwordhash,out passwordsalt);

        await _Context.Users.AddAsync(user);
        await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return user;
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#:~:text=The%20async%20keyword%20turns%20a,used%20inside%20an%20async%20method.

Answer (score 4):

> if add async keyword to any method it should wrap the returned value to a Task automaticily

Yes. One way of thinking about this is that `async` wraps the returned value (or exception) into a `Task` (or task-like). And `await` "unwraps" that returned value (or exception).